# I can't combile my project with the firebase ios sdk 2.5.1, why ? I use the uninty 4.7.1 version

Tags: c++, ios, firebase

I can't combile my project  with the firebase ios sdk 2.5.1, why ? I use the uninty 4.7.1 version

[the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnqWL.jpg)

when I select  the c++ 11 combile item:

How to fix this problem ? thanks

[unity combile bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLOgz.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Don't post a link to an image that contains the error. Include the error in the question, so that people can find it.